# How can i solve Failing connect to mail server?

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I am trying to create a working contact form, but this warning is showing when i submit form, Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set().How can i solve this issue ? can anybody help

The main code is here

```
 <?php

    if(empty($_POST) === false)

    {

       $errors = array();

       $name = $_POST['name'];

       $email = $_POST['email'];

       $message = $_POST['message'];


 if(empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true )

 {

  $errors[] = "Name, email and Message are required";

 }
   else if  (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) 

   {

     $errors[] = "This is not valid email address";

   }


if (empty($errors)=== true)  

{

$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" ;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


header('Location : index.php?sent');

exit();

}  }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="width: 350px; margin: 0 auto;">


<?php


if(empty($errors) === false)

{

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach ($errors as $error) {

     echo "<li>" .$error. "</li>";

    }

    echo "</ul>";


}

?>

<form action="" method="POST">

<p>
 <label for ="name">Name:</label> </br>   
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" 
 <?php if (isset($_POST['name']) === true) 
 { echo 'value =" ', strip_tags($_POST['name']), '"';  }  ?>>
</p>

<p>
 <label for ="email">Email:</label> </br>   
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email"
<?php if (isset($_POST['email']) === true) 
 { echo 'value =" ', strip_tags($_POST['email']), '"';  }  ?>>
</p>


<p>
 <label for ="message">Message:</label> </br>   
 <textarea name="message" id ="message">
 <?php if (isset($_POST['message']) === true) 
 { echo strip_tags($_POST['message']);  }  ?> </textarea>
</p>


<p>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</p>

</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you will find your answerhere
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page

Comment: thanks, but not get full answer

Comment: Do you have a local mailserver running? Open a shell and type `telnet localhost 25` to double check.